# Watson Assistant: Removing duplicated array items

Tags: watson-assistant

I want to be able to remove duplicated items in an array in Watson Assistant.

For example if we have the following array in a context variable:

```
["Apple","Orange","Apple","Banana","cherries", "Orange"]
```

I need it converted to:

```
["Apple","Orange","Banana","cherries"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if possible, but it worth it to take a look at SpEL:
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods-arrays-filter

You can you the filter operator to filter an array directly from the dialog.
Also the remove operator might be helpful: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods-arrays-removeValue